# Match string not containing substring in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

The question is about matching a delimited substring that does not have an unescaped dot.

I have words separated by dots. An escaped dot isn't a separator.

An example pattern for this situation using wild cards would be `asd.*.xyz`. Look the examples:

I want to match this (with the `.` escaped):

```
asd.qwe\.ert.xyz
```

or

```
asd.qwe\ert.xyz
```

But I don't want to match this (when the `.` is not escaped):

```
asd.qwe.ert.xyz
```

The slash not followed by a dot is just a char.

I tried using negative lookahead:

```
^asd\.(?:(?![^\\]\.).)*\.xyz$
```

But in this case, the last escaped dot is not allowing it to work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `^asd(?:\.\w+)*\.xyz$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2lLvHL/1).

Comment: I can't use `\w`, because the content could be anything.

Comment: Then why not `^asd.*\\\..*\.xyz$`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2lLvHL/2).

Comment: `asd.qwe\ert.xyz`, for instance, don't get matched. I think that I wasn't clear. The slash there is to escape the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match any text, and if there is any dot, you want that dot to be preceded with a backslash. You may use

```
^asd\.[^.\\]*(?:\\.[^.\\]*)*\.xyz$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XXIk6Z/1)

- `^asd\.` - start of string and then `asd.`
- `[^.\\]*(?:\\.[^.\\]*)*` - 0 or more chars other than `.` and `\`, and then 0 or more repetitions of any escaped sequence (`\\.`) and then  0 or more chars other than `.` and `\`
- `\.xyz$` - `.xyz` at the end of string.

Another way of writing the pattern is `^asd\.(?:\\.|[^.\\])*\.xyz$` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XXIk6Z/2)), but it is a bit less efficient.